# Custom elements inside ion-select-option Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

```html
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let make of makes" [value]="make?.code">
  {{make?.name}}<span class="change-stuff">example</span>
</ion-select-option>
```

I want to be able to have a span or div with some css inside the ion-select-option is this possible?
For example the text example I might want to have a green background or some other custom style

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this cannot be done, for now. [Here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/18067) you can check a GitHub issue in which someone asks exactly for that functionality.

It seems that it will be included in Ionic 6.